# How to use localization while developing magento extension?

Tags: magento, localization, locale

Currently i am developing a magento extension. I want to use the localization option which will translate data which is related to extension to other languages. But i dont know how to use it.

I have tried the following.

config.xml

```
<config>
  <adminhtml>
     <translate>
         <modules>
             <abcdef>
                 <files>
                    <default>name.csv</default>
                  </files>
             </abcdef>
          </modules>
       </translate>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Then i have placed the name.csv file in the locale folder.
But still this doesn't work for me..  Hope somebody will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to configure like below

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <IWD_OnepageCheckout>
                    <files>
                        <default>IWD_OnepageCheckout.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </IWD_OnepageCheckout>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And for admin

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <IWD_OnepageCheckout>
                    <files>
                        <default>IWD_OnepageCheckout.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </IWD_OnepageCheckout>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

pls clear browser and magento cache to test it.

hope this will sure work for you,